# mp3 player in HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, media-player

I want insert a simple mp3 player into my website. The Mp3 player must have just 2 buttons (play and pause).

I found this: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ and it seems nice but I could not make it have those two buttons. Can anyone help me find a way to insert an mp3 player in this way?

Comment: What have you tried already? Their is documentation on this site under 'getting started' for installing the mp3 player.

Answer (score 5):

I was doing a research about the subject few months ago for play sound in a game, and SoundManager is the easier way to play audio using JavaScript.

#### First way:

If you go to the documentation, you will see that **SoundManager intercepts clicks to MP3 links and plays them inline**. The script assigns additional CSS classes to the links to indicate their state (playing/paused, etc.)

```
<a href="/mp3/foo.mp3" title="Play sound" class="sm2_button">Play Link</a>
```

Check [demo and more info](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mp3-player-button/)

#### Second way

If you want to use personalized buttons instead of links, or images, or any other html element, you can use the `onClick` event to play/pause sound, for example:

Loading the sound:

```
<script>
soundManager.onready(function() {
   soundManager.createSound({id:'mySound1',url:'/audio/foo.mp3'});
"
});
</script>
```

The buttons:

```
<button id="play" onclick="soundManager.play('mySound1');return false">Play Button</button>
<button id="pause" onclick="soundManager.pause('mySound1');return false">Pause Button</button>
```

You can found more info on the [API](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/)

Answer (score 0):

In general, to play the audio file there are two main ways which are to use a premade flash object (or make it your self if you have actionscript skills) or use the HTML5 [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) and javascript controls. If you are looking for a flash player try [activeden](http://activeden.net/) which has 1000s of small players for sale and hopefully something can meet your needs.   Here is how you can [insert a flash object](http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashhtmlcode.php) into you page.

Comment: The [HTML5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) link changed.